# Gatsby.js with Wordpress installation in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I've beem building a Gatsby.js website with a headless CMS, using the previous WordPress version of the site to supply the content. Everything was working great until I moved the WordPress installation from the root to a subfolder. The GraphQL queries stopped working and the site won't build anymore.

In the **gatsby-source-wordpress** plugin documentation there is no specification how to proceed in this case. I've tried changing both the `baseUrl` and the `includedRoutes` options, but to no avail. The queries only work if the WordPress instalation is the domain root.

Here's a sample of my `gatsby-config.js` file with the plugin parameters:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
      options: {
        baseUrl: 'somesite.com/wp/',
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        protocol: 'http',
        useACF: true,
        verboseOutput: false,
        includedRoutes: [
          "/*/*/posts",
          "/*/*/media"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help will be most welcome. Cheers!

Comment: Does your wordpress itself still work when moved to a subfolder? I know that in some cases, when the prject root of wordpress changes, wordpress will no longer work. In that case, the wordpress rest api which gatsby-source-wordpress uses does also not work.

Comment: Yes, WordPress is working normally in the subfolder.

Comment: Curiously, the site stopped working when I switched it back to the root directory and I had to clear the REST API cache for the queries to work again.